# sqlite3 trigger update on any insert/update/delete

Tags: sqlite

Can I fire a trigger in sqlite whenever anything changed on a database (except for the trigger changes itself of course)? I want to save file modification date and modification revision in sqlite database, whenever anything is inserted, updated or deleted. Can I do that without applying triggers for every table?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [authorizer callback](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/set_authorizer.html), but you cannot change the database from within that function.

You must add triggers to every table.

It might be a better idea to add that code to your own database handling code.